# What is the earth's core temperature?

Tags: temperature, mantle

What is the earth's core temperature and is it really directly related to the earth's mantle?

Comment: Sorry, you need to write better questions. So now *we* have to go and look up what temperatures are mentioned in that movie??? And why are you asking; because Googling this question would have given you the answer in *less* time than it took you to write this question? The answer can also be [searched on this site](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+core+temperature) and then you find this: http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/240/is-the-earths-hot-inner-core-necessary-for-life

Answer (score 6):

The [inner core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_core) of the Earth is a large sphere of nickel-iron alloy. Surrounding this is the molten inner core which has a temperature of approximately 5400 ℃.

The [source of heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geothermal_gradient) that keeps the Earth's core hot and molten is the decay of radioactive elements, predominantly uranium, thorium and potassium.

The Mantle and Crust act as insulators for the Earth's Core.

Comment: U, K and Th in the core? Those are in the mantle and the crust, not core.